# Flask edit method not working and can't find the cause

Tags: flask, flask-sqlalchemy, flask-wtforms

I am trying to add a button that redirects me to a new page with an empty text field.
The thing is that when I click the button I get internal server error, and because there is no way the server is overloaded, that means that there is a mistake in the code somewhere. Since I can't figure it out, I am posting this question. I hope I have provided enough code and information. Also, I am not an experienced python/flask developer and I am doing this for a school project. Thank you in advance for any help or tips that you might give me  !

*EDIT* I have included everything that I need in order for this to work , the server is running and I only get an error when I press the button (bottom-most code that I have provided).

Python code :

```
@app.route('/apartments/comments/<int:apartment_id>/<int:comment_id>/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
@login_required
def comment_edit(comment_id):
    comment = Comment.query.filter_by(id=comment_id).first()
    form = CommentForm()
    if not comment:
        return render_template('errors/404.html'), 404
    if form.validate_on_submit() and comment.user_id == current_user.id:
        db.session.query(Comment).filter(
            Comment.id == comment.id).update({Comment.comment:form.comment.data})
        db.session.commit()
        flash("Comment edited Successfully!")
        return redirect(url_for('apartment_show', apartment_id=apartment.id))

    return render_template('comment_edit.html', comment=comment, form=form)
```

SQLalchemy table:

```
class Comment(db.Model, UserMixin):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, autoincrement=True, primary_key=True)
    user_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(User.id), nullable=False)
    apartment_id = db.Column(db.Integer, db.ForeignKey(Apartment.id), nullable=False)
    comment = db.Column(db.Text, nullable=False)
```

WTForm:

```
class CommentForm(FlaskForm):
    user_id = HiddenField('user_id', validators=[InputRequired()])
    apartment_id = HiddenField('apartment_id', validators=[InputRequired()])
    comment = TextAreaField('comment', validators=[InputRequired()],
    render_kw={"placeholder": "Your comment here!"}) #this is on 1 line, I think it doesnt matter but just saying.
```

comment_edit.html :

```
{% extends "layouts/layout.html" %}
{% block title %}Edit Comment{% endblock title %}
{% block head %}
{% endblock head %}
{% block body %}
  <form class="body" method="post" action="{{ url_for('comment_edit',comment_id=comment.id, apartment_id=apartment.id) }}">
    {{ form.csrf_token }}
    {{ form.user_id(value=current_user.get_id()) }}
    <label>Comment: </label><br>{{ form.name(value=Comment.comment, rows='3',cols='100') }}<br>
    <button type="submit">Edit Comment</button>
  </form>
{% endblock body %}
```

How I access and go to the comment_edit method :

```
<a style="float: right" href="{{ url_for('comment_edit', comment_id=comment.id, apartment_id=apartment.id) }}">Edit Comment</a>
```

Answer (score 1):

In this line, you're requiring 2 parameters to be passed to your route:

```
@app.route('/apartments/comments/<int:apartment_id>/<int:comment_id>/edit', methods=['GET', 'POST'])
```

That is, `apartment_id` and `comment_id`.

However, this line:

```
def comment_edit(comment_id):
```

only has one parameter when defining your function `comment_edit`.  You need to change it to:

```
def comment_edit(apartment_id, comment_id):
```